# transparent expanding circle transition animation from one layout to another on swipe

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-transitions

When users hold down on the screen, it should become transparent by their finger so they can see the underlying layout. When they continue holding down their finger and swipe, I'd like to create a transition where the transparency spreads outward from their initial holding location until the upper layout vanishes and only the layout underneath remains.

Here are examples:

[image: Swipe Transition Example Gif]
[image: Swipe Transition Example Gif]

I'm not concerned about the fancy movement of the purple / red squares; I'm just looking to find out how to create the swipe transition between two layouts.

`android.R.anim.fade_in` and `android.R.anim.fade_out` seemingly would get close to the desired effect but it would be missing the expanding circle centered on the user's finger and the transition would happen all at once instead of the intended effect of giving a peak when just held down and performing the transition only after a swipe.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this npm

react-native-expanding-circle-transition

https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-expanding-circle-transition